# Biztalk SOAP documentation

Tags: biztalk

Is there any way to include documentation in the WSDL when publishing a WCF using "Biztalk WCF Publishing Wizard" or any other way?

The wsdl documentation tags are empty by default in the wsdl, example:

```
<wsdl:documentation>
    <CreationInfo Created="2014-02-17 11:09:45Z"/>
</wsdl:documentation>
```

or

```
<wsdl:portType name="CustomerService">
    <wsdl:documentation/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RequestCustomerInfo">
       <wsdl:documentation/>
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but I'm ~95% sure what you asking can only be done with a custom Behavior.

Comment: Check out the Metadata Extensibility section of the WCF documentation.  Here's a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040(v=vs.110).aspx